# Page not showing content after generating resource file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, resources

I have a webpage with the following markup on it:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/masterpage.master" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.vb" Inherits="FASTwebV2german.admin" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="EricsWebControls" Namespace="EricsWebControls.EricsWebControls" TagPrefix="cc2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph" runat="server">
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblMenu31" HorizontalAlign="Center" meta:resourcekey="tblMenu31Resource1">
    <asp:TableRow meta:resourcekey="TableRowResource2">
        <asp:TableCell meta:resourcekey="TableCellResource1"><asp:Panel ID="pnMenuAdmin" runat="server" CssClass="pnMenu" meta:resourcekey="pnMenuAdminResource11">
                <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblMenu41" CellSpacing="10" meta:resourcekey="tblMenu4Resource11">
                    <asp:TableRow meta:resourcekey="TableRowResource1">
                        <asp:TableCell meta:resourcekey="TableCellResource2">
                            <cc2:MenuButton ID="btAdminUsers" runat="server" ButtonText="Maintain users" Bold="true" Width="150px" Height="150px" ButtonImage="Images/261.png" meta:resourcekey="btAdminUsersResource1" />

                        </asp:TableCell>

                        <asp:TableCell meta:resourcekey="TableCellResource3">
                            <cc2:MenuButton ID="btAdminImport" runat="server" ButtonText="Import stock list" Bold="true" Width="150px" Height="150px" ButtonImage="Images/269_UP.png" meta:resourcekey="btAdminImportResource1" />

                        </asp:TableCell>

                        <asp:TableCell meta:resourcekey="TableCellResource4">
                            <cc2:MenuButton ID="btAdminMenu" runat="server" ButtonText="Main menu" Bold="true" Width="150px" Height="150px" ButtonImage="Images/202.png" meta:resourcekey="btAdminMenuResource1" />

                        </asp:TableCell>

                    </asp:TableRow>

                </asp:Table>


            </asp:Panel>
 </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

</asp:Content>
```

It is written in Visual Studio 2013.
If I run the website, it shows this page with the four custom server button controls.
After I generated the resource file for multiple language support, the page remains empty.
I have not changed anything in the resource file.

If I remove the resource file, the page show normally again.

What is causing this?

rg.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Aparently there is somekind of bug in VS2013 because when I removed all meta-resource tags from the table tags, the controls started showing up.